# Correct type hint for multiple return values

Tags: python, type-hinting

Let's say that I have a function returning a single value in some cases and multiple values (i.e. tuple) in other cases.

```
def foo(a: int, b: int, flag: bool):
    if flag:
        return a
    else:
        return a, b
```

What is the correct type annotation for the return value of this fuction?

I can propose something like this:

```
def foo(a: int, b: int, flag: bool) -> Tuple[int, Optional[int]]:
    if flag:
        return a
    else:
        return a, b
```

But the main thing that I don't like in this code is that in case when the function returns a single value, that value is not a tuple. So to make this work properly I should remake the function to

```
def foo(a: int, b: int, flag: bool) -> Tuple[int, Optional[int]]:
    if flag:
        return (a,) 
    else:
        return a, b
```

Which is something that I don't want to do. Any thoughts?

Comment: "Let's say that I have a function returning a single value in some cases and multiple values (i.e. tuple) in other cases." That is a common *antipattern* that you should avoid. In any case, you are looking for a *union*. note, `Optional` is just a shortcut for a union with `None`, so `Optional[int]` is just `Union[int, None]`. In this case, you want `Union[int, Tuple[int, int]]`. Note, `Tuple[int, Optional[int]]` is **totally wrong**

Comment: Note, it would even be wrong in your second example, the type there should be `Union[Tuple[int], Tuple[int, int]]`, `Optional` means *it can be `None`*, not it can be there or not there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `typing.Union` to indicate that the function can return either one type of thing or another.  For example, if you had a function that could either return an `int` or a `str`, then it's return type would be `Union[int, str]`.

So,

```py
def foo(a: int, b: int, flag: bool) -> Union[int, Tuple[int, int]]:
```

If you're using Python 3.10, there's a better way to write a union: `int | Tuple[int, int]`

However, I should repeat the warning given in the comments.  Having such a return type is an antipattern and you should refactor your code to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.9+, you can annotate such a return value as:

```py
def foo(a: int, b: int, flag: bool) -> int | tuple[int, int]:
```